# Navigation bar button image in iOS taking 15 seconds to load

Tags: ios, iphone, button, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I am using storyboard to give an image to my navigation bar button item. However, it is taking 15 seconds to load on my iPhone 6! My image size is only 1kb, but the view controller does have a `viewdidload` and `viewdidappear`. What could be happening that my custom 3 lined image is taking so long to load on that nav bar button in iOS?

Update: I have even tried doing programmatically and there is still a delay.

```
 UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-icon.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 6)];
    [self.emaily setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Do you have any timings? Time to start on device in app delegate, time until viewDidLoad, time until viewWillAppear, time until viewDidAppear etc. Sure its not just taking 15seconds to download the app to the device?

Comment: Can you post your code, maybe there is something in your code that could be causing that issue, the best practique is to test it in the hardware device, the simulator has fails and takes a loot to start .

Comment: The rest of the view controller is loaded and functional

Comment: Where is this code located?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the storyboard element and then just doing it programmatically solved it.

```
 UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-icon.png"];
    _emaily = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:backButtonImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(emailappcrea:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = _emaily;
    [_emaily release];
```